# ATA error: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)

Tags: debian, sata

Today I boot my laptop (HP pavilion dv6) running debian 7, and the window manager won't start. I just get over and over again errors as:

```
[###.######] ata6: COMRESET failed (errno=-32) 
[###.######] ata6: COMRESET failed (errno=-32) 
[###.######] ata6: COMRESET failed (errno=-32) 
[###.######] ata6: reset failed, giving up 
[###.######] ata6: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen t2 
[###.######] ata6: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed 
[###.######] ata6: SError: { DevExch }
```

and the window manager never starts. I have not been able to find out what is connected to ata6. Here is when it gets weird -to me at least-:

- I rebooted on an ubuntu pendrive, and everything is ok. I scanned the harddrive and it seems to be ok.
- I logged in (it let's me log in the terminal but the window manager won't start) and did

  $ dmesg | grep -i sata | grep up
  [###.######] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gpbs (SStatus 123 SControl 300)

So apparently there is nothing on ata6. I also followed the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/244944/linux-ata-errors-translating-to-a-device-name) to find out what was on ata6 but nothing. Maybe is the CDROM which is failing? Also, to me it was weird that this started happening today. So if I do

```
$ sudo grep 'Nov 7' /var/log/kern.log | grep 'ata'
```

I get nothing. But if I do

```
$ sudo grep 'Nov 3' /var/log/kern.log | grep 'ata'
```

I get a long list of errors. So this errors have been going on for a while, but only today it started to stop the window manager to starting up...

How do I stop this error from not allowing me to start GNOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue I also had. Two issues, in fact.

- The error message looks like the one I'm getting [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306104/exception-emask-0x10-sact-0x0-serr-0x4060000-action-0xe-frozen-t2). It is probably hardware related but I can't tell what it implies.
- As for the window manager not starting, it could be the logs filling up the system partition, not allowing `Gnome` to write in `/tmp`. I had this problem with `Mate`, with an explicit error message.

Obviously, the root cause is the `ATA error` stuff, but assuming you don't know what to do about it and it does not seem to affect the machine (apart from the logs growing and growing), you'd like to avoid that partition being filled.

I asked about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299320/rsyslog-filling-up-var-log-puts-the-system-down). I didn't find any satisfying answer. Putting `/var/log` in a dedicated partition (or virtual filesystem) is the only safe solution I know.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a problem with a SATA-connector. After I unplugged the device and plugged it back everything was fixed. Filesystem check shows no errors, everything is perfect.