# exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4060000 action 0xe frozen t2

Tags: syslog

I get all those errors in kern.log and I don't know how to investigate them.

I'm not even sure which one is the most relevant for a title to this question.

AFAIU, this is likely to be hardware related. But I can't even tell which part. Hard drive? Motherboard?

```
Aug 27 18:11:13 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1601.220021] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448042] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448052] ata2: reset failed, giving up
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448071] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4060000 action 0xe frozen t4
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448072] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448074] ata2: SError: { PHYInt CommWake DevExch }
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448080] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Aug 27 18:11:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1603.448082] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:11:17 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1605.708014] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:11:17 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1605.708021] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:11:25 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1613.448023] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:11:27 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1615.708012] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:11:27 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1615.708019] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:11:35 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1623.448033] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:11:37 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1625.676012] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:11:37 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1625.676018] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 33 secs
Aug 27 18:12:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1658.448030] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:12:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1660.740012] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:12:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1660.740021] ata2: reset failed, giving up
Aug 27 18:12:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1660.740038] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4060000 action 0xe frozen t3
Aug 27 18:12:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1660.740040] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Aug 27 18:12:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1660.740042] ata2: SError: { PHYInt CommWake DevExch }
Aug 27 18:12:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1660.740046] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:12:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1663.004017] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:12:15 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1663.004024] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:12:22 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1670.740017] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Aug 27 18:12:22 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1670.740022] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:12:25 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1672.968026] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:12:25 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1672.968034] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:12:32 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1680.740019] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:12:35 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1682.972013] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:12:35 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1682.972020] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 33 secs
Aug 27 18:13:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1715.740025] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:13:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1718.064012] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:13:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1718.064021] ata2: reset failed, giving up
Aug 27 18:13:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1718.064040] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4060000 action 0xe frozen t2
Aug 27 18:13:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1718.064042] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Aug 27 18:13:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1718.064044] ata2: SError: { PHYInt CommWake DevExch }
Aug 27 18:13:10 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1718.064049] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:13:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1720.452011] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:13:12 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1720.452019] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:13:20 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1728.064018] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Aug 27 18:13:20 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1728.064022] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:13:22 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1730.548016] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:13:22 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1730.548023] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:13:30 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1738.064025] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:13:32 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1740.292017] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:13:32 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1740.292024] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 33 secs
Aug 27 18:14:05 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1773.064017] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:14:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1775.356013] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:14:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1775.356021] ata2: reset failed, giving up
Aug 27 18:14:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1775.356037] ata2: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4060000 action 0xe frozen t1
Aug 27 18:14:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1775.356038] ata2: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
Aug 27 18:14:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1775.356040] ata2: SError: { PHYInt CommWake DevExch }
Aug 27 18:14:07 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1775.356045] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:14:09 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1777.616011] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:14:09 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1777.616019] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:14:17 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1785.356016] ata2: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Aug 27 18:14:17 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1785.356021] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:14:19 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1787.584014] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:14:19 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1787.584020] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 8 secs
Aug 27 18:14:27 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1795.356022] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:14:30 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1797.840013] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:14:30 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1797.840019] ata2: reset failed (errno=-32), retrying in 33 secs
Aug 27 18:15:02 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1830.356017] ata2: hard resetting link
Aug 27 18:15:04 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1832.648012] ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-32)
Aug 27 18:15:04 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1832.648020] ata2: reset failed, giving up
Aug 27 18:15:04 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1832.648034] ata2: EH pending after 5 tries, giving up
Aug 27 18:15:04 bouzin-lilou kernel: [ 1832.648036] ata2: EH complete
```

I removed all USB devices, disconnected the DVD drive, and changed the sata cable of the hard drive. I now have only one hard drive, with a new (and known to work) sata cable.

I also checked the hard drive with smartmontools:

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Hitachi HDT721032SLA380
Serial Number:    STA205MC1JLU3X
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 346d5a40d
Firmware Version: ST2OA31B
User Capacity:    320 072 933 376 bytes [320 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sat Aug 27 18:31:06 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                ( 4710) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  79) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   112   112   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       220 (Average 223)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3605
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       8720
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3602
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3723
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3723
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   146   146   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 10/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8711         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8710         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

AFAIU, there was no issue found.

I don't see any abnormal behavior, except those messages filling up my log files.

FWIW, this machine as a nvidia graphic card and uses nouveau (no proprietary driver).

Comment: -32 is `BROKEN_PIPE` and every couple of seconds the kernel resets the communication with the disk because the disk is not replying as fast as it says it will.  I bet on an issue with the disk controller.  SMART would not find it since it would need a stress test.  (SMART gives the diagnostics that the disk firmware gives it, if the firmware is screwed SMART would assume that there are no diagnostics for certain things).

Comment: Thanks. The disk controller is a part of the HD, as shown [here](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hdc.htm), right? Not a part of the MoBo? Replacing the disk might solve this, then? Apart from the logs being filled up, is this an issue? I mean does this mean the disk is slowly wearing off? I think it has been like this for a while. Should I perform a stress test? How?

Comment: Yup, I suspect the HDC.  The easiest test is simply to use a different disk and see if it happens.  Problems with the HDC does not necessary mean problems with the disk itself.  I had a disk that had a completely crashed HDC but when I connected a new one it worked.  (But first test a different disk in your setup, it may as well be the disk which in turn gives problems to the HDC firmware)

Comment: FYI I got this when connecting an external esata drive to my laptop's esata port. I'm thinking its a sata driver issue